# What do you use to upload big files on? (For Slower Internet Connections)

Tags: big, files

I know a lot of people would want some recordings of the Muslim Prayers from a Mosque so I recorded one a couple of days ago, just so you know its not a super duper fantastical recording cause it was one on a H4n on my cousins apartment terrace, (I'll try to get better ones one day) but anyway its like 9mins and 300mb and I can't upload it and share it like I usually do on Soundcloud cause my internet is too slow (512kbps), and even when I do that I need to upload then in mp3. What other alternatives are out there that I could use? I've used dropbox before but I don't think it would be any faster.

Here's a recording at Jumeira Beach, Dubai UAE I think it was three mosques doing their morning prayer at probably 6 or 7am (48k/24). http://ge.tt/8tEAWKD [Uploaded on 08/02/2012 I think it won't be available again in 30 days]

Comment: If the bottleneck is your internet connection, why not put the file(s) on a usb-stick and go somewhere where they have fast internet?
Dropbox, wetransfer and all the other upload sites have similar speeds which are way faster than what your home connection can handle.
Alternatively, you can pack the file into split archives (winrar does this for example) that are smaller in size and upload them piece by piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ge.tt

No limit, files are available to download immediately (though it means people wait with unfinished downloads while you upload), and it's five characters long.

Comment: I think this would be the best thing for me to use lol thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not to concerned with time, then I recommend Dropbox. Great way to collaborate and share files without the need to do lots of emailing and external websites, etc. It also keeps backups incase you remove a file accidentally, therefore not needing to reupload.

Comment: +1 for Dropbox as a personal and professional tool for those who don't have an anonymous FTP setup. For pro's, Basecamp is also great, but with limits on filesize and a much broader feature set.

Comment: Additional, you can manage the files on portable devices like iPhone, etc. via a web interface or their free apps.

Answer (score 2):

www.wetransfer.com is great, no pop up ads or codes that you need to put in to download, no queues either. Just pretty advertisement while your file downloads at max speeds.

Lovely! :) and a 2gb limit.

Comment: I'll second that, WeTransfer is great.

Comment: Yeah this seems pretty I'll try it out, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox here with free 10gb account, works perfect for slower connections as it will automaticly upload the files to cloud as long as you have the native app running on the background. You also get extra 250mb (up to 10gb) of space by suggesting dropbox to your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Google docs for file transfers and have been really happy.  I think you get 2GB of free space???  I pay $5/yr for 20GB of space. You can manage who has access to the file (everyone, only you, specific people etc).  Not to mention all the other benefits of google docs.  Great service!